# Android Studio Emulator no longer responding

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm learning Android studio and my Android studio Emulator was working fine until a recent windows Update happened. When I tried to load the emulator it's no longer responding.

In the Run log I get

> Error while Launching activity

it's not specifying what error it caused.

Things I did to troubleshoot

I tried to increase and decrease the RAM.
Tried to remove the .gradle and .idea folder and synced the files again.

But no luck - Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go in the Emulator setup and reinstall the emulator device after removing it.

Comment: I tried to do that. I removed my current device and reinstalled with a lower API. Unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Does your emulator gets started though? i mean without building and running your application, can you start in as a stand alone process?

Comment: I did start in stand alone process. Emulator won't respond after loading the Google intro image.

Comment: Then i suppose you would have to reinstall the ADB from the SDK. Go to SDK manager->SDK tools and reinstall the Android Emulator.

Comment: Thank you. After reinstalling ADB emulator is working now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It because of your graphic card latest update . Install your pervious version of your graphic card. It helped me